# What kind of sockets or methodology out there in network programming to create voip or online games

Tags: java, android, mysql, sockets, networking

i'm currently learning about sockets with using java. I'm learning about TCP sockets and UDP sockets including multicast sockets. And i'm just wondering, what other kind of sockets or networking mechanisms out there that i can use to make voip and real time online games and such? And which one is mostly used among industries?

Comment: UDP is typically known as the faster of the two protocols and tends to be used for "real time" things such as streaming, online games, and more. The disadvantage is the delivery of the data is not guaranteed so you'll have to figure out how to handle lost packets.

Comment: Hey Talon. Thx so much for giving me amazing tip =p yup i guess i need to study more about UDP to creat VOIP and stuffs thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, if you can tolerance with any packet loss UDP is better, otherwise TCP. Base on this principle, voip generally use UDP (for data packets not control packets).